# URL Rewrite in .htaccess causing internal 500 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

SOLVED: I've been having an .htaccess rewrite problem with rare cases causing internal 500 errors on my site.

I setup a Rewrite rule in my .htaccess to redirect 
http://mysite123.com/churches/ANY_NUMBER_HERE/any_name_here 
to 
http://mysite123.com/churches.php?churchid=ANY_NUMBER_HERE , but the end-user will still see http://mysite123.com/churches/ANY_NUMBER_HERE/any_name_here

It works perfectly unless they type http://mysite123.com/churches/ANYTHING_BUT_NUMBERS_HERE or if they type numbers without a trailing slash.

This is my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^churches\/([0-9]+)\/.*$ /churches.php?church=$1 [L]
```

Basically, is there a way I can change my rule/regex to make the htacess point to a 404 error page if they type any letters, special symbols, or numbers WITHOUT a trailing slash? I need to avoid the 500 internal server error, it's hurting my SEO

EDIT: I'm getting this error code in the server logs:

```
[Tue Aug 04 20:48:44 2015] [error] [client 24.107.131.201] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

EDIT #2: I solved the problem by adding this rewrite rule that stops loops:

```
#STOP LOOPS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(stats/|missing\.html|failed_auth\.html|error/).* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Comment: Look in your error log files to see what's causing the 500 error

Comment: Here is the server error code: [Tue Aug 04 20:48:44 2015] [error] [client 24.107.131.201] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: I fixed the problem using this rewrite rule that stops loops: `#STOP LOOPS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(stats/|missing\.html|failed_auth\.html|error/).* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]`